# converting [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil]; to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Getting an error here. Racking my brain. Tried all sorts of combinations.

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSDictionary' that accepts an argument list of type '(object:(Int), forKey: CFString!)'

```
// configure the pixel format -  Obj-C
// videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

// Swift       
videoOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(object: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), forKey:kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey)
```

Comment: Why is there a comma after 32BGRA and not a close paren?? the forKey is being passed there, not to the dictionary constructor..

Comment: ok thanks. But now I'm getting these 2 errors: http://i.imgur.com/WqZy8LR.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**update: Swift 5.7**

```
videoOutput.videoSettings = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
]
```

Comment: Wow thanks. why did it work? I don't understand it. It's like Inception. A cast within a cast within a cast :)

Comment: Works brilliantly. So it's no longer a dictionary if you remove NSDictionary? Or does the square brackets keep it a dictionary? What type is `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` originally? Just a string?

Comment: It is a CFString https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelBufferRef/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Pixel_Buffer_Attribute_Keys. That second version it is just a Swift Dictionary with a single key

Comment: The second version `videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]` is throwing a fatal error in swift 2 `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @lan the correct syntax is [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]

Comment: not working to me, I got this error Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: No wonder. This has been posted almost 8 years ago. Swift 2

Answer (score 1):

This has been changed in **Swift 4.x**, with the following working for me:

```
captureVideoDataOutput.videoSettings = 
    [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
```

Comment: not working to me, I got this error Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the type would be `[String: Int]`.

Actually, looking in the Xcode docs, it says that the value can either be a single number or an array. If it's an array then the type would be `[String: [Int]]`.

So you should be able to say:

> let aVideoSetting: [String: Int] =
>   [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
>   videoOutput.videoSettings = aVideoSetting

I'm still not 100% with the interoperability of Cocoa types and Swift types, so that might not be perfect, but it's close.

You could also rewrite your code to create an NSDictonary in swift syntax:

```
let aPixelFormat = NSNumber(int: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
let settingsDict = NSDictionary(aPixelFormat 
  forKey:  "numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA")
```

Comment: Not working. This code on Git is exactly the Swift version of my Obj-C code. https://github.com/bradley/iOSSwiftOpenGLCamera/blob/master/iOSSwiftOpenGLCamera/CameraSessionController.swift. `videoDeviceOutput.videoSettings = NSDictionary(object: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA), forKey:kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey)`.  There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: not working to me, I got this error Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: “This code is exactly the Swift version of my Obj-C code.” No. Every single character matters. You need to EDIT YOUR QUESTION to show your exact code, along with the specific line which is giving an error, and the exact error.